# Extbase fe_user findByUsergroup

Tags: typo3, extbase

I would like to list all fe_users who belong into a specified usergroup. The following works fine **if the user has only one usergroup assigned**:

```
$users = $this->userRepository->findByUsergroup($this->settings['fachgruppe']);
$this->view->assign('users', $users);
```

But there will be users with more than 1 group assigned and the result will be empty then. The usergroups are not an m:n relation but just a comma separated string, as it seems: `11,12,28` But thats how this is built and I have no control over that.

(How) Is it possible to get all users associated to multiple usergroups?

Answer (score 1):

For multiple query values and a single value property you'd normally use `QueryInterface::in()`, for a single query value and a multi-value property you'd use `QueryInterface::contains()`.

But here you have multiple query values and a property with multiple values. Thus you need a custom repository method like this:

```
public function findByUserGroups(array $userGroups): QueryResultInterface
{
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $constraints = [];

    foreach ($userGroups as $userGroup) {
        $constraints[] = $query->contains('userGroup', $userGroup);
    }

    // Use logicalAnd() instead if all groups must match
    return $query->matching($query->logicalOr($constraints))->execute();
}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to extend the fe_user repository to use a custom function but the damn thing doesn't work. ._. Could you help me there please, then I could try out your code.

Comment: You'll need your own repository and I'd strongly recommend to always do this. The one shipped by TYPO3 is not really meant to be used in every project since it cannot reflect every "domain".

Answer (score 1):

As this is the old way TYPO3 stores sets you might use the old ways to find a relation: do it by a plain SQL query like this:

```
 SELECT * 
     FROM fe_users 
     WHERE concat(",", usergroups, ",") LIKE "%,3,%"
```

The concatenation is necessary to have a proper string to compare and identify the group correctly (no false positives with finding group 3 where a relation to group 13 is stored).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below extbase query.

```
$users = $this->userRepository->findByUserGroups($this->settings['fachgruppe']);

public function findByUserGroups($userGroups)
{
  $userGroup = explode(',', $userGroups);
  $query = $this->createQuery();
  $query->matching(
      $query->in('usergroup', $userGroup)
  );
  return $query->execute();
}
```